# Docker - Using macvlan network, attempting to publish port?

Tags: docker, networking

I currently have a docker macvlan set up as such:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=10.30.140.0/22 --gateway=10.30.143.254 -o parent=br0 NETNAME1
```

I'm wanting to give this docker container an IP so it can be accessible from anywhere within our company, so when I try to run my docker container as such:

```
docker run --net NETNAME1 -it --ip=10.30.141.43 -p 10.30.141.43:80:4873 --expose=80 verdaccio/verdaccio
```

I can access this IP from everywhere other than the host that is running the container, and I'm not quite sure why. I also wanted to make it so the host port is 80, container port is 4873. But I can only access this if my url is http://10.30.141.43:4873

Is there any reason why it wouldn't be redirecting to 80?

Comment: if I understand how macvlan network works in Docker, the container is completely exposed over the IP address and the parent interface of host (more or less like host network). Port redirect or expose directive are ignored. So, in order to do a port redirect you should use the  iptables on container.

Answer (score 0):

For the routing problem , there might be some overlap between host network and the docker network , try to use a different subnet for docker network such as `192.168.10.0/24` or something else like `--subnet=10.10.140.0/24.`

For the port mapping , remove extra stuff from docker run and do -p 80:4873

```
docker run -d -net NETNAME1 80:4873 verdaccio/verdaccio
```

**Testing:**

These commands works fine , and I can access port 80 on the host.

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=10.30.140.0/22 --gateway=10.30.143.254  NETNAME1
docker network ls
docker run -it --rm --net=NETNAME1 --name verdaccio -p 80:4873 verdaccio/verdaccio
docker ps
```

Comment: How would I go about specifying what IP the container should use on that network if I remove the --ip flag and the <ip> portion of the publish flag?

Comment: the container should pick an ip automatically , the same way as it is getting in case of deafult bridge network

Comment: @Kyler45 I just tested it on my machine and it works

Comment: But my host subnet is different from the docker subnet so there is no issue with anything